# Optimizing mysql group by with large linking table

Tags: mysql, group-by, many-to-many

I've been reading a lot on this and still get 30+ seconds per this query, while I'm certain it should work a lot faster.

The problem is this:

Having a large linking table (40 millions rows, data consisting of 650MB and index representing 1.8 GB) defined as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `glossary_entry_wordList_1` (
  `idTerm` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `idKeyword` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `termLength` smallint(6) NOT NULL,
  `termNumberWords` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `termTransliteralRFC` mediumint(9) NOT NULL,
  `keywordLength` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `termLanguage` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idKeyword`,`idTerm`),
  KEY `termTransliteralRFC` (`termTransliteralRFC`),
  KEY `termLength` (`termLength`),
  KEY `secondPrimary` (`idTerm`,`idKeyword`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_general_ci
```

and a small temporary table defined as follows:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `foundIDs` (
  `searchId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `searchedKeywordId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `similarKeywordId` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `partsMatched` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `sumSimliarParts` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `keywordLength` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `fuzzyMark` float NOT NULL,
  `keywordDjb2` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `smallKeyword` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`similarKeywordId`),
  KEY `searchId` (`searchId`),
  KEY `searchedKeywordId` (`searchedKeywordId`),
  KEY `partsMatched` (`partsMatched`),
  KEY `keywordLength` (`keywordLength`),
  KEY `smallKeyword` (`smallKeyword`),
  KEY `keywordDjb2` (`keywordDjb2`)
) ENGINE=MEMORY DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

I need to retrieve from `glossary_entry_wordList_1` all the `idTerm` that are associated with at least 50% (or any other percent) of the `idKeyword` in the table `foundIDs`.

Practically, I need to find all the sentences that contain x words.

For this I use a query like this (please mind the conditional data is here only by example):

```
SELECT glossary_entry_wordList_1.idTerm, 
count( glossary_entry_wordList_1.idKeyword) as termsMatched , 
sum(foundIDs.keywordLength) as sumTermLength, 
sum(foundIDs.fuzzyMark)/100 as sumFuzzy, 
sum(foundIDs.partsMatched*foundIDs.keywordLength)/100 as sumLengthSimilar, 
foundIDs.searchId
FROM foundIDs
inner join glossary_entry_wordList_1 on glossary_entry_wordList_1.idKeyword = foundIDs.similarKeywordId
WHERE
foundIDs.searchId = '17559' and
glossary_entry_wordList_1.termTransliteralRFC >= '824.4' and
glossary_entry_wordList_1.termLength>= '8.55' and
glossary_entry_wordList_1.termLength<= '18' and
foundIDs.smallKeyword = 0
GROUP BY glossary_entry_wordList_1.idTerm
HAVING count( glossary_entry_wordList_1.idKeyword)>'2'
order by null
```

And this is the Explain:

```
id  select_type  table  type  possible_keys  key  key_len  ref  rows  Extra  
1 SIMPLE foundIDs ref PRIMARY,searchId,smallKeyword searchId 4 const 8 Using where; Using temporary 
1 SIMPLE glossary_entry_wordList_1 ref PRIMARY,termTransliteralRFC,termLength PRIMARY 3 foundIDs.similarKeywordId 146 Using where
```

The engine behavior is like this:
- The smaller word length (1-2 letters) the longer the query response (obviously as they have lot more associations)
- The more words in the searched table (foundIds), the longer the query

Any ideas on how to improve the query response?

Thank you,

Comment: Could you confirm the `EXPLAIN` output match the query and tables specifications and issue you describe in your question? According to that, MySQL has only to examine 8x146 rows. Or do I have some trouble interpreting what I see?

Comment: I believe that you should try other approach for your project, maybe MongoDB will help you with your problem.

Comment: Sylvain, Indeed that is the output for that case. I forgot to mention that foundIDs has only 4 rows, for this explicit case (search).